# React - Are variables set up in render accessible/readable on client side?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code for the render of my elements :

```
render() {
     let bla = "boum boum"
     let blaHash = sha(bla)
     return ( <div>{blaHash}</div> )
}
```

and I was wondering if the client could in the code, or in the console, access the variable bla and get the "boum boum" text. Is it a way to save a data before hashing ? If not (which I think it is not) What would be a solution to get the hash without compromising the bla variable?

Answer (score 0):

Yes your hash key could be viewed from client side.
I think it is better to fetch hashed value from your server side and use that value in render function afterwards. For instance:

```
GenKey() {
    $.getJSON('https://yourserver.com/api/{keyGen}')
      .then(({ result }) => this.setState({ key: results }));
  }

  render() {
     this.GenKey();
     let blaHash = this.state.key;
     return ( <div>{blaHash}</div> )
    ));
```

For even more secured hashing you could also generate a random pattern on client side and append that pattern with your server side key and then generate a hash. Also pass that generated pattern to pass along to server when you call your service to store the hashed value.

Comment: If you assign a state to the bla variable it will surely be visible on client side too no ? I don't see how your solution is hiding the "bla" variable more than mine as in both case they are declared in the render function.

Comment: I think then its a better idea to hash your string on server side instead.

Comment: Post your string to server side which will return a hashed value. Use that value afterwards.